# How to use both #anchor and ?destination parameter in a node/edit url?

Tags: 7, uri

I have a long page containing a node edit form and I wish to direct the user to a specific part of the page.

My URL is `/node/12364/edit?destination=node/12360`.

Where in the URL should I add the anchor?

I tried `/node/12364/edit#anchor?destination=node/12360` but it doesn't work. The anchor is not used, the user isn't directed to a specific part of the page.

If I enter `/node/12364/edit#anchor`, it works but I need the destination parameter.

Comment: Drupal comes with the [url()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/url/7) function as well, where you can set a fragment (#) in the settings array. That way it is always in the right place.

Comment: When adding content, the url() function is not neccessarily a factor. Combining destination and anchors in URLs is relevant for content editors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Page fragment is always passed after the query string. Otherwise, the browser will recognize the query string as part of the fragment.

Here's how your URL should look like:

```
/node/12364/edit?destination=node/12360#anchor
```

However, if you were asking how to pass anchor to the *destination* page, you simply need to use encoded hashtag instead. Here's how the URL should look like in this case:

```
/node/12364/edit?destination=node/12360%23anchor
```

`%23` is encoded `#` character. See [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) page for more info.